# Lubuntu 18 freezes/hangs on shutdown or reboot

Tags: lubuntu

I've  Acer predator laptop with 8th Gen laptop i5 8300H chip. It also houses Intel UHD 630 iGPU and GeForce 1050Ti dGPU. I've installed lubuntu it a while back.

I want a distro with minimal resource usage, hence the lubuntu as of now.

Anywho, the first time it updated some software (including kernel). While I tried to reboot after a software update, it just freezes/hangs. This is happening for shutdown or reboot attempt (from GUI or command). Sometimes the taskbar at the bottom disappears and just desktop background remains as is or it just freezes.

I've to literally press power button 5-9 seconds to shut it down. Not sure if its bug, but there is absolutely no way to understand whats happening.

So far I've tried:

-I've added "acpi=force" line in grub, update-grub. Futile.
-systemctl poweroff etc. No luck.

-I am able to get it reboot laptop using Magic_SysRq_key (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

While Alt+SysRq pressed, if I type REISUB keys then it reboots. Though pressing REISUO doesn't shutdown it. kind of strange, but that problem for another day. From magic_sysrq + REISUB its clear that the x server/windows system is kind of having some issue.

I am just utterly confused here. Does anyone have any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try blacklisting nouveau

there are several ways to do this:

1. add to grub command line: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
2. add text "blacklist nouveau" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and run "sudo update-initramfs -u" and reboot

Comment: I have not installed proprietary nvidia drivers. Don't want to this soon. Blacklisting nouveau will bypass dGPU as there are no proprietary drivers in place

Comment: Genci, so I edited GRUB and now it's working. BTW if am not allowing nouveau modules to get loaded, is the system now using onboard UHD 630 drivers now? Sorry, but I am completely new to Linux as Desktop. Also lspci showing both VGA adpaters listed and noueau is still being shown as module for 1050Ti VGA